# How to ask a country-specific version of a more general question?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question, new-users

I have a question about my Role-playing Games Stack Exchange post: [How to find a tabletop RPG group open to newbies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133986/how-to-find-a-tabletop-rpg-group-open-to-newbies)

My question is similar to this one : [Where can I find other RPG players?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/where-can-i-find-other-rpg-players)
I tried to use the various online resources given by the answers, with no success.

Would it be ok to ask for resources that could help finding a group in a specific country ?

---

Note : It's possible that there are no such groups where I live, in this case there would be nothing to add to the original question's answers.

Answer (score 6):

I am afraid that [Where can I find other RPG players?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/where-can-i-find-other-rpg-players?rq=1) is really as far as we can go.  Asking for more specific items is basically a shopping question, and suffers from all the same reasons that those are off topic here - suggestions will be outdated quickly, no real way to establish a best answer, and so on.

Comment: Given the votes here and that it's been a while, I've closed the French question as a duplicate of the abovelinked question.

Answer (score 5):

I'd be open to us offering region-specific advice: we're becoming a large enough community that we could have enough members for that to be viable.

However rather than using my diamond to reopen the question unilaterally, I'm going to leave it to the community vote the question open if they're interested in that.

Comment: how do we vote?

Comment: @Boulash You need 3000 reputation to vote on closing/opening questions.